# How can i index pages on Zend Optimizer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-index, zend-optimizer

Greetings i have a problem with this site http://artwoodflooring.co.uk/ . For some reaseon i can not index the pages, if i try to acces http://artwoodflooring.co.uk/home it returned with the domain/host page. after i spen 3 4 hours i look at some tutorials on the internet and chenge the .htaccess from `AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php3 .php4 .php .phtml`
 to `

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  ## uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  ## getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  ## remove trailing slash
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
  #RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  $1 [R=301,L]

  ## turn off index.html, it is for offline mode
  RewriteRule ^.*index.html$ index.php [QSA]

  ## no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

`
Now it returns with 500 Internal server error
Why?? What can i do to avoid this thing and index those pages so google can see this pages ??
Are the pages a sort of script??
There is an Option there on the admin pannel with Do not index page, but is not selected
Best Regards Titus